# Shipping method under certain amount

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

Ok, I have a tricky one. So it is about Magento 1.9
So if order is equal or under 12 eur I should have flat rate or shipping rate of 3 eur. But if over 12 I should have another shipping method.

So basically up to 12 eur I should have flat rate shipping method, and above 12 eur I should have another shipping method while first one disappears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's depended on what another shipping method you want to show if the order is above 12 eur. I think we have 2 cases in this situation. First is free shipping and second is another price smaller or greater than 3 eur

1. Free shipping case: you can use promotion in this case.

   - Goto admin>Promotion>Shopping cart rules
   - Create Shopping Cart rules
   - On this condition tab put logic shopping

     > Subtotal > = 12
     >   [image]
     >   and put below rules like screenshot[image]
   - Enable  Flat rate from System -> Configurations -> Shipping Methods and put your shipping Charges.It is work when subtotal less 12
2. Another shipping price which smaller or greater than 3 eur. In this case, I will suggest you use the `Table rate shipping method`. You can disable all other shipping methods and use `Table rate shipping method` only

   - Enable `Table rate shipping method` and choose the condition is `Price vs. Destination`
   - Change the scope config to `Website`
     [image]
   - Click on `Export CSV` button to get the table rate csv configuration file
   - In the `tablerate.csv` file, you can set the `order subtotal (and above)` column match with your condition. This is an example of setup Table rate shipping method using the condition `Price vs. Destination` `https://www.sitepoint.com/set-up-table-rate-shipping-in-magento/`
   - After put your configuration in the csv file, you need to import it to magento. You will see an import field below the export field.

Hope it works as you need!